# Cookies created server side using ajax is not accessible as http call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cookies

I have one web page index.php where I am executing one ajax

```
//index.php
<script src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get('ajax.php', function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });

    })

</script>
```

Noe on server side I am creating few cookies in ajax.php

```
//ajax.php    
    <?php

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
setcookie("Phone", '111111', time() + 86400);
print_r($_COOKIE);
?>
```

Now I am opening another page test.php and trying to get this cookie, But I am getting cookies, I tried to print cookies

```
//test.php
    <?php
print_r($_COOKIE);
?>
```

but those cookies does't print..

Comment: Is the cookie being set? You should post the complete `ajax.php` script up until where you set the cookie. Note that you cannot output anything before you use `setcookie` as cookies are sent as part of the header. Also note that the default path causes cookies to be available only in the folder where they are being set.

Comment: I have updated the what ajax.php is doing ....

Comment: Just check in the developers tools if the cookie is there; Cookies tab in firebug or Resources -> Cookies in Chrome.

Comment: No i didn't found those cookies in developer tools...

Comment: So post the whole `ajax.php` script.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies set via PHP over AJAX aren't going to get set in the client, because they are defined in the HTTP headers that the browser receives when the page loads. This is why you can't call setcookie after you've sent output.

Cookies are pretty easy to set with javascript though: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

If the PHP script is doing calculations that are needed in the cookies, just pass them back as JSON, and then set them via javascript.

I don't know how well it works, but here is a jQuery plugin for managing cookies: http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/